# Why is php fgetcsv function timing out?

Tags: php

I have just a basic understanding of PHP but I managed to write a small plugin for wordpress for a calculator/form I needed for my site that asks the user to input humidity % and temperature and based on that it retrieves a value from a CSV and displays a total value for the amount of water the machine can generate.

[image: screen shot of the form]

When I tested it on MAMP it was working as I wanted it to, but having shifted it to my wordpress site, the page keeps timing out after 5/10 minutes.

PS: I've had to use a csv file for to retrieve the coefficient values based on the users input, while it's only 45KB I am not sure what the problem is.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: watercalc
Plugin URI:
Description: Calculates water generation
Version: 1.0
Author: Chefattack
Author URI:
*/

//WordPress Hooks
add_shortcode('wcalc', 'run_bc');
function run_bc()
{
// If the submit button has been pressed
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
// Check number values
if(is_numeric($_POST['temperature']) && 
is_numeric($_POST['humidity']))
{

// Calculate total
function getValueFromCSV($csv_name) {
  $humidity= $_POST['humidity'];
  $temperature= $_POST['temperature'];
  $file = fopen($csv_name, "r");
  while (!feof($file)) {
    $arr = fgetcsv($file);
    if ($arr[0] == $temperature) {
      $coefficient= $arr[$humidity - 4];
      if($_POST['models'] == 'pod')
      {
        $total = round($coefficient * 0.0287801747544059 * 0.03 *60 * 24 *365);
      }
      if($_POST['models'] == '36K')
      {
        $total = round($coefficient * 0.0287801747544059 * 0.1 *60 * 24 *365);
      }
      if($_POST['models'] == '55K')
      {
        $total = round($coefficient * 0.0287801747544059 * 0.15 *60 * 24 *365);
      }
      if($_POST['models'] == '110K')
      {
        $total = round($coefficient * 0.0287801747544059 * 0.25 *60 * 24 *365);
      }
      if($_POST['models'] == '180K')
      {
        $total = round($coefficient * 0.0287801747544059 * 0.5 *60 * 24 *365);
      }
      if($_POST['models'] == '365K')
      {
        $total = round($coefficient * 0.0287801747544059 * 1 *60 * 24 *365);
      }

      // Print total to the browser
      echo "<h4> Water Generation at $humidity% Relative Humidity and $temperature C<br>Per Year: ~ {$total} ltrs.</h4>";
    }
  }
  fclose($file);
}
// Function Calling
getValueFromCSV('akvo-values.csv');

} else {

// Print error message to the browser
echo 'Numeric values are required';

}
}

?>

<form method='post' action='<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>'>
<label>Temperature (Celcius)</label><br>
<select name="temperature" class="form-control" style="width: 150px; 
display: block">
    <?php for ($i = -20; $i <= 60; $i++) : ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></option>
    <?php endfor; ?>
  </select><br>
<label>Relative Humidity (%)</label><br>
<select name="humidity" class="form-control" style="width: 150px; display: block">
    <?php for ($i = 5; $i <= 100; $i++) : ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></option>
    <?php endfor; ?>
  </select><br>
<label>Choose Akvo Model</label><br>
<select name="models" class="form-control" style="width: 150px; display: block">
  <option value="pod">Akvo Pod</option>
    <option value="36K">Akvo 36K</option>
    <option value="55K">Akvo 55K</option>
    <option value="110K">Akvo 110K</option>
    <option value="180K">180K</option>
    <option value="365K">365K</option>
</select><br>
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Calculate" class="btn btn-primary" />

</form>

<?php
}
```

Comment: why do you 'have' to use a csv and not a database?

Comment: break the loop of file read after echo-ing, just call: `break;`

Comment: break; didn't work.

Comment: I don't have to use a CSV, but I have elementary knowledge of php and I used a piece of code that did something similar using a CSV.